# Bootstrap 4 tooltip in small container positioning issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I'm having issues with Bootstrap 4 tooltip positioning. I have a scrollable container, which is narrow enough for an item only. For an item I want to display a tooltip on the right. Tooltip for an item doesn't fit into container and Bootstrap incorrectly positions as can be seen on the image below and this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y1f4nLkc/1/).

[image]

If I make container wide enough for tooltip there is no issues.

How can I fix the issue and have my tooltip on the right even if it doesn't fit in container?

Here is HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <div class="block" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et adhuc delenit quo. Imperdiet theophrastus ius ut, alii sensibus complectitur sit eu.">123</div>
    <div class="block" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et adhuc delenit quo. Imperdiet theophrastus ius ut, alii sensibus complectitur sit eu.">123</div>
    <div class="block" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et adhuc delenit quo. Imperdiet theophrastus ius ut, alii sensibus complectitur sit eu.">123</div>
    <div class="block" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et adhuc delenit quo. Imperdiet theophrastus ius ut, alii sensibus complectitur sit eu.">123</div>
    <div class="block" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et adhuc delenit quo. Imperdiet theophrastus ius ut, alii sensibus complectitur sit eu.">123</div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');

#container {
    width: 120px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.block {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  min-width: 80px;
  min-height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It because `popper.js` is used to absolute position the `tooltip`. You can override this behavior using the **`data-boundary`** option on the tooltips...

https://www.codeply.com/go/Ueu4813mhH

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <div class="block" data-toggle="tooltip" data-boundary="window" data-placement="right" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et adhuc delenit quo. Imperdiet theophrastus ius ut, alii sensibus complectitur sit eu.">123</div>
    <div class="block" data-toggle="tooltip" data-boundary="window" data-placement="right" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et adhuc delenit quo. Imperdiet theophrastus ius ut, alii sensibus complectitur sit eu.">123</div>
    <div class="block" data-toggle="tooltip" data-boundary="window" data-placement="right" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et adhuc delenit quo. Imperdiet theophrastus ius ut, alii sensibus complectitur sit eu.">123</div>
    <div class="block" data-toggle="tooltip" data-boundary="window" data-placement="right" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et adhuc delenit quo. Imperdiet theophrastus ius ut, alii sensibus complectitur sit eu.">123</div>
    <div class="block" data-toggle="tooltip" data-boundary="window" data-placement="right" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et adhuc delenit quo. Imperdiet theophrastus ius ut, alii sensibus complectitur sit eu.">123</div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot!